# How to create a nameplate extension?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, configurable-product, extensions, custom-options

I am looking for Nameplate extension similar to the one found here:  https://www.soufeel.com/necklaces/design-your-name-necklace

Where can I get the extension or how would I add this functionality myself?

Comment: The site you linked to uses magento 1, and this is labeled both 1 & 2..  Which version are you using?

Comment: I am looking for both version but mainly Version 2

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure whether or not this is an extension.  It could just be custom programming that is specific to the site plus custom options/configurable attributes.

In any case, there are a variety of extensions that can be found with a simple google search for "Magento Personalized Products" or something similar.

This one seems to be the best fit for you that I found:

[Magento Personalized Products - Milople.com](https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/personalized-products.html)

Here are a couple more that should work, but might be overkill for your needs:

[Custom Product Builder - Buildateam](https://marketplace.magento.com/buildateam-m2-custom-product-builder.html)  -- This one is free but focused on images and only available for M2

[Premium Online Product Designer - CMSmart](https://cmsmart.net/magento-extensions/magento-premium-online-product-designer-extension) - Does both M1/M2 (like Milople.com), but may go further than you are looking to go, making it more complicated than necessary, and it is a litle more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a [Personalized product solution for Magento 2](https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/magento/personalized-products-solution). It provides the solution in many industries like gifts, crockery, furniture, curtains. As per your requirement, this will fulfill your all needs.